# How to stop div from moving with on hover

Tags: css, html, hover

I want to increase the size of some images when hovering over them. 
Please have a look at the example below. It's the option Test (3rd image):

http://livingfunky.webresponsive.co.uk/index.php/curtains/hand-made-curtains/test-hand-made-curtain.html

```css
.swatches-container .swatch-img,
.swatches-container .swatch-span {
  margin:0 2px 2px 0;
}

.swatches-container .swatch-img {
  border:1px solid #eee;
  max-width:30px;
  max-height:28px;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.swatches-container .swatch-img.current {
  border:2px solid #333;
}

.swatches-container .swatch-span {}

.swatch-img:hover {
  border:1px solid #eee;
  max-width:60px;
  max-height:46px;
  left:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
}
```

The problem I have is that when I hover over the third image, the div moves. How can I prevent this from happening?
Thanks

Comment: By increasing the size of the content you increase the height of the div, my suggestion is trying to set it to absolute, that way you will detach the picture from the current div, thus avoiding the resize

Answer (score 2):

The deal is that you need to have your images positioned as `absolute`, so that the `swatches-container` is not resized if they get bigger.

Thus, you can put your images into a `<div class="swatch-img-block"></div>` which keep having the size of the little image, so the flow isn't modified by your growing image and your images will be `absolute` positioned relatively to these `<div>`

You can do this with this CSS:

```
.swatches-container .swatch-img-block
{
    display:inline-block; /* displayed as inline elements */
    position: relative; /* so the images can be positioned relatively to this */
    width:30px; /* keeping the image size */
    height:28px;
}
```

and by adding `position:absolute` in `.swatch-img:hover{ }`.

EDIT: looks like for compatibility issues, it is better to replace `.swatch-img:hover` selector by `.swatch-img-block:hover .swatch-img`. This way, the image is made bigger if the pointer is on the `<div>` containing the image (the space of the image when it is little). Also, it avoids problems with images moving out of the pointer.

Here is a working jsFiddle : [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/8secC/1/)

Comment: I tried your link and it didn't work for me. I'm using Chrome Version 28.0.1500.72. The hover event didn't do anything for me, just wanted to give you a heads up.

Comment: @Mike You are right, Chrome looks to have some problems with moving a `:hover` object. The trick is there to replace `.swatch-img:hover` by `.swatch-img-block:hover .swatch-img`. This way, all browsers are happy. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: It works like a champ now! Hopefully user1977156 looks at your code ... good job ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can set the img to absolute positionning when hovered, also the `swatches-container` have to be relatively positioned :

```
.swatches-container
{
  position:relative;
}
.swatch-img:hover {
  position:absolute;
}
```